# DB2 error in fields

Tags: sql, db2

I have some old soft, which connected to DB2 database and in some operation database I get this error.
I dont have help for this program and cant decompile it for check logic.

`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC="";", "FIELD1", "FIELD1",;<space>, DRIVER=3.65.97`

I just wanted to know in which case this error can occured? 
In this columns i have only smallint without nulls.

Answer (score 0):

This error (SQLCODE -104 ) also known as SQL0104N is usually a programming mistake by the persons who write/maintained the old software you are using.

Your DBA can find that bad code if you involve the DBA.

If you have no DBA you can also get the java program (whatever is using the jdbc driver) to trace the SQL, or use jdbc trace to view all the SQL coming from the old software and find the bad SQL in the trace. You can then arrange for someone to fix it, if there is any business impact.

If the old software is just scripts that run against a Unix/Windows DB2, then you can just read the code (look for admin_cmd references) and see the mistake.

If the DB2 database is on i-Series or z/OS then different causes are possible, but they are always programming mistakes.